# Date format on GridView, ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, date, gridview

I want to return the date part only from my database when I execute a SELECT statement. 
(in the statement below: Task.ST_Date)

```
SELECT Task.Details, Task.Pr_ID, EmTask.T_ID, Task.Ref_ID, Task.ST_Date
FROM Task
INNER JOIN EmTask ON Task.Ref_ID = EmTask.T_ID
WHERE EmTask.Em_ID = 214432
    AND Task.STATUS = 'WAITING'
    AND Task.ST_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120)
        AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE() + 6, 120)
```

This statement works, but when I view it in a gridview, this format shows: **2/3/2017 12:00:00 AM**
[image]

Is there any way that I can modify the format into 'yyyy-MM-dd'?

*within the database (MSSQL): date datatype , yyyy-MM-dd format 
[image]

Comment: You have to provide DataType="System.DateTime" and DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" with BoundField of GridView itself as shown in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Task.ST_Date, 120)
```

or in C# with `Eval`

```
Text='<%# Eval("ST_Date", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %>'
```

or

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="ST_Date" dataformatstring="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can format the GridView column to show date in your desired format

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="YourDateField" HeaderText="SomeHeader" 
                    DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"  />
```

Or if you have TemplateField

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Number">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="txtDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval("dateTime")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), convert(DATE, '2/3/2017 12:00:00 AM'), 126)
```

output

```
DATE
2017-02-03
```

YOU can change in query  it self

```
SELECT TASK.DETAILS, TASK.PR_ID, EMTASK.T_ID, TASK.REF_ID,CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, TASK.ST_DATE), 126)
FROM TASK
INNER JOIN EMTASK ON TASK.REF_ID = EMTASK.T_ID
WHERE EMTASK.EM_ID = 214432
    AND TASK.STATUS = 'WAITING'
    AND TASK.ST_DATE BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120)
        AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE() + 6, 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide `DataType="System.DateTime"` and `DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` with BoundField of GridView itself as shown below.

```
<asp:BoundField DataType="System.DateTime" DataField="YourDateField" HeaderText="SomeHeader" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Format the GridView column according to desired format:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Save Dt">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblSDate1" runat="server" HtmlEncode="false" Text='<%# Eval("SDate", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Task.Details, Task.Pr_ID, EmTask.T_ID, Task.Ref_ID,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Task.ST_Date , 120) as ST_Date
FROM Task
INNER JOIN EmTask ON Task.Ref_ID = EmTask.T_ID
WHERE EmTask.Em_ID = 214432
AND Task.STATUS = 'WAITING'
AND Task.ST_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120)
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE() + 6, 120)
```